# (Copy Constructor) How does the object passed as parameter to initialize another object have access to the private members?

Tags: c++, class, object

Example code:

```
class my
{
    int x;
    public:
    my(int a)
    {
        x = a;
    }
    my(my &obj)
    {
        x = obj.x;
    }
.
.
}

int main(void)
{
    my object1(5);
    my object2(object1);
    return 0;
}
```

How is object2 initialized by passing it object1? As far as I can see object1 can't access the member `x` directly, then how does it help in initializing object2?

Comment: A class is implicitly its own friend.

Comment: @NeilKirk That description is great. C++ classes are narcissistic =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access control (public/private/protected) controls whether a *piece of code* can legally refer to *a name of a class's member.* Individual objects don't play a role here; the whole problem is just about code and names.

Let's compare the constructor from your question, a friend function and a free function:

```
class my
{
  int x;

  friend void fr(my&);
public:
  my(my &obj)
  {
    x = obj.x;
  }
};

void fr(my &obj)
{
  obj.x += 1;
}

void nonfr(my &obj)
{
  obj.x += 2;
}
```

Take the statement `x = obj.x;`. A statement is a piece of code. Where is that piece of code? Inside the constructor of class `my`. So it's a part of the class and so it can access the name `obj.x`.

Next, the statement `obj.x += 1;`. Where is that piece of code? Inside the function `fr`, which is a friend of class `my`. It's a friend, so it can access the name `obj.x`.

Finally, the statement `obj.x += 2;`. Where is that piece of code? Inside the function `nonfr`. `nonfr` is an ordinary function unrelated to class `my`, so it has no right to access the names of private (or protected) members of class `my`, so it will fail to compile.

---

Side notes:

Normally, a copy constructor should take its parameter by reference to const, like this:

```
my(const my &obj)
```

Copy constructors which take by non-const reference can modify the source object, and viable use cases for them are extremely rare. Not to mention that they prevent copying from temporaries, since those can't bind to non-const references.

Also, it's generally preferable to use mem-initialiser-lists instead of assignment inside the constructor, because the latter first initialises the member and then assings to it. So in total, the constructor should look like this:

```
my(const my &obj) : x(obj.x)
{}
```

Not to mention the fact that unless you need special handling in the copy constructor (which you don't here), you shouldn't declare it at all and let the compiler generate it for you. See [Rule of Zero and Rule of Three](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) for more information.

Comment: thanks, although this wasn't put up in the questions this was the exact source of confusion for me. Thank you for picking this up from my comment. I will update the question later to add this bit.

Answer (score 5):

Private applies to *classes* not *objects*. Any object of class X has access to the private members of all other objects of class X.

Comment: @jack-aidley Isn't it that private members can only be accessed within the class and not by its objects?

Comment: @aste123: What do you mean by *"...within the class and not by its objects"*?

Comment: Any member of the class is "within the class". It does not matter which object (or whether any object) they were called on.

Comment: @aste123 This isn' Java. In C++ classes aren't first-class objects; they're declarative. Any `my` object in your example can, via its members or the class static methods, access the guts of another `my`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, but this answer seems to say different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271214/why-can-my-object-not-access-its-own-private-member-variable-c

Comment: @aste123: Think of it this way: The modifier says that that member is private, which means it can only be accessed by code that's part of the class. That code is owned by the *class*, not individual objects. The code has access to private information on any instance (object) of the class, not just the one it knows as `this`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: How does that change anything from Java? (And what all does first-class mean...)

Comment: @aste123: The OP tried to access a private member from outside the class. No wonder it didn't work. (THe answers explain the error well enough)

Comment: @aste123: The difference in that question/answer is that the code trying to access the member isn't in the class. It's in `main`, where `cout << car1.width << endl;` is being executed. So it doesn't have access to the private information in the `Car` class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, thanks I get it now. Then why can't a non friend function access the private members of the class whose object is passed to it for example: `func(my obj){obj.x = obj.x +1;}`.If func is not a friend of the my class, it can't access x but since we are using `obj.x`, it should access it right?

Comment: @Deduplicator In java a *class* is [itself an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605067/treating-classes-as-first-class-objects) (a little like a template argument in C++, but runtime, not just compile time). I bring it up because the OP is apparently confused about what constitutes a "class" when saying things like: "Isn't it that private members can only be accessed within the class and not by its objects". Regardless, it looks like the OP has it now. (Edit: or.. *not*).

Comment: @aste123: "If func is not a friend of the my class, it can't access x" - yes, that's exactly what a `private` access restriction is supposed to prevent. Only members and friends of the class can access its private members. "since we are using `obj.x`, it should access it right" - no, `private` means that it can only be accessed within members or friends of the class, whether it's accessed via an object of the class, or in any other way.